# flex4 how to pass value to spark image

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I'm learning Flex4 and found that the new spark image class doesn't have data property. Since in Flex3, I use data property in mx image class to pass certain value indicating data source represented by the image, so that when you handle events of such images, you can easily found the data sources.

I doubt there is some new mechanism in Flex4 to do such things, but itemrenderer seems only work for list, combobox etc. or do I have to put spark image in a certain container which can store data? I miss data property in mx Image but spark image's contentcache seems nice and I do believe there is some way to work with spark image.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to inherit from  and add the properties you need?

The biggest advantage (in contrast of using the data object) is the gain of type safety. If the source is an URL, you may even put URLRequest in the image component.

Example:

```
package basicComponent
{
    import spark.components.Image;

    public class MyImage extends Image
    {

        private var _sourcePath:String;

        public function get sourcePath():String
        {
            return _sourcePath;
        }

        public function set sourcePath(val:String):void
        {
            _sourcePath =val;

            //but here some logic...
            //e.g. refresh, access cache...
        }

        public function MyImage()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```